# How to determine points costs of Tau unit enhancements?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tau

I have been trying to figure out which are the points costs for the several enhancements to tau units, but there is not a single comprehensive list for that. Sometimes model stats sheets have 'may take a markerlight and target lock (15pts),' while some other sheets just say 'may take two items from the support systems list' without specifying any cost. Does it means that I get those items for free (included in the unit price)? Another confusing case is that of Crisis Battle Suits: they 'may take take up to three items from the ranged weapons and/or support systems lists.' For some units different ranged weapons cost different amounts of points, so it sounds strange that crisis suits have access to all of them at the same (zero) cost.

Apparently the older codex had a table on page 95 with all the costs, but I only have access to the 2015 edition and such table is gone.

Am I correct in assuming that such enhancements cost points when a cost is mentioned but are otherwise free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There still is a table for the Ranged Weapons and Support Systems on Page 74 of the 2015 edition of the book. The did clean up the locations of special rules/equipment in newer editions, but if you're used to the older editions this can be hard to find.

Generally Ranged weapons are 14 points and other support systems range from 5-25 points each. One nice thing about weapons all having the same points is you cna swap crisis suit builds very easily. None are free unless the rules explicitly state so, for exmaple: "X comes equipped with with a Burst-Cannon which you may upgrade to a Smart-Linked Missile system for 25 points" or something similar.

Comment: If you have your codex handy, you can just look in the section where it explains what all of the Ranged Weapons and Support Systems do. The points costs are all in that section.

Comment: Correctly. Page 74. I can't believe that I missed it! Perhaps you should edit your answer with that info so that it is more visible.

Answer (score -1):

It is very strange question, as long as all lists (Vehicle Equipment, Ranged Weapons, Support Systems, Signature Systems) have points cost for each option. I'll recommend download elder 2012 codex, which can be used as 2015 one with updates printed in Kauyon book.

And ranged weapons ARE NOT 14 pts., they are all divided to 5 (+5 for twin-linked): 5 for flamer, 10 for burst cannon and 15 for any other. Vehicle battle systems cost from 1 to 15 pts., support systems -- from 3 to 50 and signature systems cost from 2 to 25 (50 for FE).